# "call" or <str> in batch script unfortunately removes certain characters from a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, call, trim

I don't understand why the following batch :

```
REM echo off
setlocal
set u64=aDI0NDcxOQ==
set p64=SGZzemxwNzc3
call :atob usr "%u64%"
call :atob pwd "%p64%"
schtasks /Run /S aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd /U %usr% /P %pwd% /TN "My Scheduler Task Name"
goto :EOF

:atob <var_to_set> <str>
for /f "delims=" %%I in (
   'powershell "[Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([convert]::FromBase64String(\"%~2\"))"'
) do set %~1=%%I
goto :EOF
```

removes the last 2 '=' characters of u64 as you can see with the following result :

```
C:\Users\lambda>REM echo off
C:\Users\lambda>setlocal
C:\Users\lambda>set u64=aDI0NDcxOQ==
C:\Users\lambda>set p64=SGZzemxwNzc3
C:\Users\lambda>call :atob usr "aDI0NDcxOQ=="
C:\Users\lambda>for /F "delims=" %I in ('powershell "[Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([convert]::FromBase64String(\"aDI0NDcxOQ \"))"') do set usr=%I
C:\Users\lambda>set usr=Exception calling "FromBase64String" with "1" argument(s): "Longueur non
C:\Users\lambda>set usr=valide pour un tableau de caractères Base 64 ou une chaîne."
C:\Users\lambda>set usr=At line:1 char:1
C:\Users\lambda>set usr=+ [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([convert]::FromBase64String("aDI0NDcxOQ "))
C:\Users\lambda>set usr=+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\lambda>set usr=    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
C:\Users\lambda>set usr=    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException
C:\Users\lambda>set usr=
C:\Users\lambda>goto :EOF
C:\Users\lambda>call :atob pwd "SGZzemxwNzc3"
C:\Users\lambda>for /F "delims=" %I in ('powershell "[Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([convert]::FromBase64String(\"SGZzemxwNzc3\"))"') do set pwd=%I
C:\Users\lambda>set pwd=Hfszlp777
C:\Users\lambda>goto :EOF
C:\Users\lambda>schtasks /Run /S aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd /U   /P Hfszlp777 /TN "My Scheduler Task Name"
Erreur : Syntaxe incorrecte. Valeur attendue pour '/U'.
Entrez "SCHTASKS /RUN /?" pour afficher la syntaxe.
C:\Users\lambda>goto :EOF
```

Without the last 2 '=' characters, the number of character of my Base54 value u64 is not a multiple of 4, therefore it cannot be decoded.
We can see in the output that it is working fine with p64.
usr only stores a space...
And I want to stick with a .bat file for now, not a .ps1 script please.
Thanks for your help.
I have tried several combinations of surrounding with "", but so far with same result.

Comment: This isn't a PowerShell question. Please don't use the PowerShell tag.

Comment: As we already mentioned in the [scripting guys forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-Us/home?forum=ITCG), your life will be easier if you don't try to write your script using cmd.exe shell script (batch) and instead use PowerShell.

Comment: unfortunaltely the code you proposed in powershell didn't work. And I was also curious to know how to do it in batch as it is almost working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `FromBase64String(\"%~2\")` to `FromBase64String('%~2')` also fixes the problem in my testing.  I can't say why the equal signs are being converted to a space, but I can say that in PowerShell, single-quoted strings are treated as literals, whereas double-quoted strings allow evaluation of the string's contents.

From a cmd prompt, try

```js
powershell "\"$null\""
```

then try

```js
powershell "'$null'"
```

and observe the different behavior.

Alternatively, you could assign a variable to `%~2` in your batch subroutine, then refer to it in the `env:` scope within PowerShell.

```js
:atob <var_to_set> <str>
set "str=%~2"
for /f "delims=" %%I in (
   'powershell "[Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([convert]::FromBase64String($env:str))"'
) do set "%~1=%%I"
goto :EOF
```

Comment: I had tested the solution you first put in your comment of my question, which was changing FromBase64String(\"%~2\") to FromBase64String('%~2') and it worked as well indeed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not in the `call`, but in how the parser decides what to handle as a delimiter when preparing the command to execute.

While there are some options (escape characters or delayed expansion) for this case the simplest one (from the batch point of view) could be to wrap the access to the variable inside a `for` replaceable parameter

```dos
:atob <var_to_set> <str>
    for %%V in ("%~2") do for /f "delims=" %%I in ('
        powershell "[Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([convert]::FromBase64String(\"%%~V\"))"
    ') do set "%~1=%%I"
    goto :EOF
```